# Set files to ownership of current directory in Python

Tags: python, permissions

I'm working on a Python script that creates text files containing size/space information about the directories that the script is run on. The script needs to be run as root, and as a result, it sets the text files that it creates to root's ownership.

I know I can change the ownership with os.fchown, but how do I pass fchown the uid and gid of the directory that the script is running on?

Comment: Of course, you would get the `dirpath` by doing `os.getcwd()`, or whatever function call you needed to get the directory in which file creation was to take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
import os, stat
info = os.stat(dirpath)
uid, gid = info[stat.ST_UID], info[stat.ST_GID]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Would I be able to give os.stat() 'os.getcwd()' rather than a static "dirpath"?